# Possible execution result

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, java-threads

```
    public class Messager implements Runnable {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Messager("Wallace")).start();
        new Thread(new Messager("Gromit")).start();
    }
     private String name;
     public Messager(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
     public void run() {
      message(1);
      message(2);
    }
     private synchronized void message(int n) {
      System.out.print(name + "-" + n + " ");
     }
  }
```

is : **B. Wallace-1 Gromit-2 Wallace-2 Gromit-1**
a possible result of the execution of this code?

Comment: Are you just expecting a yes or no answer? Why do you have doubts about the output?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : yes, can you answer please? my guess is no.

Comment: Why do you guess no? Explain that in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a possible result.

`message(1)` and `message(2)` are executed in the order.

So, `Gromit-1` must be followed by `Gromit-2`.